# iPhone simulator folder not in Application Support

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios-4.2

I am creating an application that write some data to the database. For checking I need to open the database in applications.

I think it should be in

~/Library/Application Support/iphone simulator....

I have not found the iphone simulator folder in Application Support.I have installed ios 4.2, and simulator is working properly.

Where can I find it?

Comment: Try this method.My answer posted here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731518/no-iphone-simulator-folder-in-application-support/8784630#8784630

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to see the file system on the iOS simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480607/is-there-any-way-to-see-the-file-system-on-the-ios-simulator)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Xcode versions 3.x-5.x

Simulator usually is installed together with SDK so most probably you should look (e.g., if you installed Xcode 3.1 and SDK 4.3 in their default locations) within:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iOS Simulator.app
```

Apps that are installed on your iPhone Simulator should be (if for example compiled for iOS 4.3) located in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/[app GUID]
```

If you are looking for .sqlite database within Application, it should reside in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/[app GUID]/Documents/[appname].sqlite
```

## Xcode 6

The simulator devices are located in:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
```

so your application data (e.g. application database in app Document folder) will be in

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[simulator device id]/data/Applications/[app GUID]/Documents/[appname.sqlite]
```

Comment: Yes It is there. But how can I view the database file.

Comment: If you want a free SQLite viewer, go here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlvue-lite/id433341470?mt=12

Comment: There's a nice add-on for FireFox available: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: We are now up to simulator 5.0 and 6 is in beta 4 stage. I would suggest testing with: ls -la ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/*.*/Applications

Comment: was getting error `"tmp" could not be removed because you do not have permission` when trying to launch simulator, clearing out `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/` and resetting the settings in the simulator fixed everything

Answer (score 15):

On Mac OS X 10.7 the users/[username]/Library is **hidden**. Reveal it using:

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

Comment: Run these 2 commands in Terminal to see this directory in the Finder: 1) defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
2) killall Finder

Answer (score 9):

In IOS5, follow this step

1. Right Click finder in Dock.
2. Click 'Go to Folder'.
3. Give folder name as "/Users/'USER NAME'/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/"

It will take you there.

Comment: This works, thanks heaps. **PEOPLE** Ensure that you type in your Macs name where it says "User Name"

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: When you run the simulator, it creates a directory under your home directory located at:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/
```

When you install an application onto the simulator, it creates a sandbox for the application in a path that looks something like this:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/user/Applications/<GUID>
```

Where `<GUID>` is a directory with the name being a GUID assigned to the application during the installation process.  The GUID isn’t particularly necessary to find for you application, and the path to your application’s sandbox can be found with a quick display of command-line foo. From the `~/Library/Application Support`, run:

```
Deminem$ find ./ -name "AppName.app"
```

And, voila. It will return a list of all the sandbox directories which contains this application. The "private" data for your app inside the directory:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/user/Applications/<GUID>/Documents
```

Good luck! ;)

Comment: But here is not a directory named iphone simulator in Application Support.

Comment: I mentioned run inside the `~/Library/Application Support`, so it will list down all the sandbox paths for your app. Or you can run it from users directory `/Users/Deminem` which will show you all the paths for this file.

Comment: Do I need to reinstall iphone simulator

Comment: Have you execute the above command? and if you can print the trace here so i can track the problem.

Comment: Yes I have run find ./ iphone\ simulator, find: iphone simulator: No such file or directory

Comment: Ah men! i told you run this command on terminal: `find ./ -name "YourAppName.app"`. But before running this make sure that you've created the app in the sandbox by run your project one time.

Comment: This way we will know the exact location of your apps sandbox. Or may be helps to tackle down the actual issue.

Comment: The actual solution I found on another Stack Overflow article. i had the same issue. The iPhone Simulator folder is hidden by default: type this in a terminal screen: chflags nohidden ~/Library/

Answer (score 2):

Now on ios 8 the application data is located at `Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEVICE NUMBER/data/Containers/Data/Application/APPLICATION ID`

Comment: Note that APPLICATION ID above changes every run, but 
-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:] and NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) will always use the current value. Your code should not depend on the full path to persist between runs of the application.

Answer (score 2):

On XCode 8. the sqlite file is in

`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DEVICE ID ]/data/Containers/Data/Application/B4813EE5-CC8E-4728-872E-41918AD1C14D/Documents/[APPLICATION NAME].sqlite`

I don't know the mean by "B4813EE5-CC8E-4728-872E-41918AD1C14D".

The way to get DEVICE ID:

1. Click to dropdown the simulators list

[image]

2. Click "**Add Additional Simulators...**"
   [image]
3. Select the simulator you are using

Answer (score 1):

We are now up to simulator 5.0 and iOS 6 is in beta 4 stage. All previous answers and comments are out of date.

I would suggest testing with

```
ls -la ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/*.*/Applications
```

To answer the specific question about databases

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/*.*/Applications -name \*.sqlite
```

That should last until Apple makes a drastic change.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about the SQLite file used by Core Data – if so, that file *should* be in `~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/`[AppID]`/Library/` (assuming you're simulating iOS 4.2). If it's not there, I'm not sure where else it would be.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here

/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications

or

/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications

Answer (score 0):

You can also write two lines of code that will tell you exactly where your app is located.

```
NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSLog(@"%@", appFolderPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10, Xcode 8.3.3,

Find the Document path from 
`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)`

then you can find the sqlite file in path printed