# Reading iPhone files from PC / Mac programmatically

Tags: iphone, macos, detection, data-transfer

Applications like iPhone Explorer can show the contents for each installed iPhone application on Mac OS X (even on non-jailbroken devices) when iPhone is connected using USB-cable. I'm trying to do something similar, programmatically copy some files from my iPhone app's folder.

I have done some experiments with open-source frameworks/products built to use iTunes-framework, like iPhoneBrowser and MobileDevice Library. I can connect to iPhone, now the problem is how to enumerate Apps folder items? iPhoneBrowser or MobileDevice Library don't support or provide any easy way for that. Even when hardcoding my application path to iPhoneBrowser it still refuses to display the folder. iPhone Explorer can read the folder without any trouble on the very same device, so it is definitely possible.

Second problem is getting path to apps, on each device they have different path with some hash number folder names. How to 'decrypt' the paths so that I can access my app folder on every device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the app enumerate use another protocol， you may find some in this https://github.com/phildrip/fruitstrap

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a open source program that works on Windows, here is the github project url:

https://github.com/Moligaloo/iPhoneFS

It can access files on jailbroken iPhone/iPod/iPad (non-jailbroken devices files are limited accessible).
It can also enumerate apps on iDevice.