# iOS8 Document directory path

Tags: ios8, nsdocumentdirectory, nsdocumentdirectory-ios8

Issue in `iOS8 document directory` path detection:

1. Am using following code to store downloaded attachments from my app into `documents directory` path.

   ```
   //-- Store data to documents folder
   NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[ [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
   NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileName]];
   [self.downloadedMutableData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
   ```
2. Using following code to retrieve document form path

   ```
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   ```

   - Everything works fine in `ios7` simulator & device.
   - But its not locating correct path in `ios8` device & also in simulator too.
   - Please anybody help to store & retrieve a document in `ios8`.

Comment: if you have saved your files somewhere else than the `Document` folder, you are probably in a big trouble on _iOS8_, because the file-structure has been changed and isolated from the application bundle's path... what is your question anyway?

Comment: In iOS 8 document director path location changed. [Check this answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198840/document-directory-path-of-ios-8-beta-simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application `Documents` directory, it works on every iOS version:

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code to access document directory works fine in iOS 8.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL *directory =
    [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
```