# Is there an equivalent for the "adb shell" on iOS

Tags: android, ios, shell, filesystems

I need to access the filesystem of the App I am devolping on the `iOS Simulator`. On `Android` I start up an `Emulator`, go to the console and type `adb shell`, followed by `run-as com.MYAPP`. Here we go. I am in the filesystem and can do stuff like `mkdir`, `rm -R ...` etc. Is something like that possible with `iOS`?  There must be some sort of file manager... All the [resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW1) I find tell me how to programmatically access the filesystem. But I know that already...

Comment: @VarunNaharia you only linked to another answer. Commenting on my Q would have been enough to do that. Hence I wont upvote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Document Directory Path of iOS 8 Beta Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198840/document-directory-path-of-ios-8-beta-simulator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a simulator's filesystem at the below path:

`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`

Choose the simulator folder correctly by checking the `devices.plist` file at the above Path and open the correct simulator folder. You can find the app data at `data/Containers` path inside the simulator folder.