# No iphone simulator folder in Application support

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to add some videos to iPhone simulator for my project. I saw similar posts and noticed that I should post videos to

> /library/Application Support/iphone simulator/4.0/Applications/APPLICATIONGUID/Documents

But I don't have an iPhone simulator folder in my Application support. I ran my application in Xcode. My iOS simulator is already open and running but still I don't see that folder.

Is there any other way to add videos to iphone simulator?

Answer (score 17):

You should look in your home library ~/Library/ not the root /Library/

Note that in Lion this is now hidden by default, you can show it by typing

> chflags nohidden ~/Library/

in the terminal

Comment: Or just hold down Option when popping the Finder's Go menu.

Answer (score 2):

are you in the system root and not your home folder?

Comment: Thanks guys. I was in my system root folder. Now, I am looking at the correct folder. I did post my .m4v video files there but I am not able to see those videos in the simulator. When I run,my application crash.

Answer (score 2):

1) Go to iPhone simulator

2) Reset it

3) Open trash

4) You see 4.0 / 4.2 or 5.0(me).

5) Copy it to **/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform** folder

6) Reset simulator again

7) Open trash again

8) Right click on 5.0/put back

9) That's it

Now u have fixed it....

---

I've done.working perfect for me..

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way is this:

1. Open up finder
2. From the finder menu bar (at the top) find the go option and select "Go to Folder"
3. Put your path - /library/Application Support/iphone simulator/4.0/Applications/APPLICATIONGUID/Documents - in the go to folder option.
4. The folder that you want opens up.
5. You can now pull it to your favorites in the left hand side of your finder.