# No iphone simulator folder in home library > Application support

Tags: macos, ios-simulator, xcode4.3

I installed the xcode_4.3.1_for_lion.dmg on my mac 10.7.3. I need an iphone simulator folder to install the iapps. No iphone simulator folder in Application support

~/Library/Application Support/?

Checking in home library only.. ~/Library/...

Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of [How to install iPhone application in iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator). I don't see any method of flagging a question as duplicate, though.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer at following post.You should clear your trash folder and reset it.For more detail click below link.

[No iphone simulator folder in Application support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731518/no-iphone-simulator-folder-in-application-support/8784630#8784630)