# Objective C - iPhone simulator path is not found in MAC LION

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, osx-lion

Am using Mac lion for developing iPhone application, there I created database and copied into documents directory of the application, But the path to the applications documents directory not found in my lion, even the "Library" folder is not available under the lion's username.

I searched completely on my lion for the folder Library which has "Application support" following with "iPhone simulator" is not found. I checked for the moving of deletions of the folder, But it's not happened.

Anybody knows for what I can't find the folder.

Please advice me, I not available what can I do to resolve this.>

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem, but to access your Library, select finder, and on the status bar press "Go", and press the Alt/Option key, Library will appear on the list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your library folder is bydefault hidden so you will have to unhide it.
You can get information about showing hidden files [here](http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2008/04/show-hidden-files.html)

**Edit1**:
You can also go to library in following way

- Right click on Finder icon of your Dock
- Click on "Go to Folder".
- Type `/Users/yourusername/Library.
- Click on Go.

**Edit2:**
you can permanently unhide the folder with following command

```
chflags nohidden /Users/yourusername/Library
```

Comment: Great answer... Just an addition, you can permanently unhide the folder 
`chflags nohidden /Users/yourusername/Library`

Answer (score 3):

From the Xcode menu on top, click preferences, select the locations tab, look at the build location option.

You have 2 options:

```
Place build products in derived data location 
Place build products in locations specified by targets
```

By default, your derived data directory will be under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName/Build/Documents.

Please confirm whether you got ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also check my answer.
See my answer in this post.You should clear your trash folder and reset it.For more detail click below link.
[No iphone simulator folder in Application support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731518/no-iphone-simulator-folder-in-application-support/8784630#8784630)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following solutions: http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/access-hidden-user-library-files.html

Apple made the user library folder hidden by default with the 10.7 release. If it's necessary to access these files for Adobe-related troubleshooting, use one of the following methods to make the user library content visible.

**Method 1**

In the Finder, choose Go > Go To Folder. In the Go To Folder dialog, type ~/Library Click Go.

**Method 2**

Hold down the Alt (Option) key when using the Go menu. The user library folder is listed below the current user's home directory.

Note: After you open the Library folder, you can drag the Library icon from the top of that window to the Dock, Side Bar, or toolbar. That way, it's readily accessible.

**Method 3**

The following method makes the user library folder permanently visible.

Note: Adobe recommends that only advanced users use this method.

Launch Terminal from Mac HD > Applications > Utilities. From within Terminal type the following command and press Return:

chflags nohidden ~/Library Enter the system administrator password, if prompted, and press Return.

Note: The System administrator password is not visible as you type it.

Close Terminal for this change to take effect.